# In Django Admin how do I disable the Delete link

Tags: django, django-admin

I've managed to disable the "Delete selected" action. Easy.

But a user can still click on an item and then there's the red Delete link at the bottom.

Answer (score 145):

Simple :)

```
class DeleteNotAllowedModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Other stuff here
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: The action is still in the dropdown, but throws a forbidden 403. To clean it up you have to follow my solution. Plus do this as well.

Comment: Do you want to remove the dropdown too, in case of that, follow radtek's solution

Comment: @radtek You are correct, that the action will still be in the dropdown, but the OP did state that he's already managed to disable the delete selected action. So this is all that's necessary.

Comment: Thats fine, I posted the complete solution 2 years ago.. not an issue.

Answer (score 94):

If you want to disable an specific one that isn't custom do this. In django 1.6.6 I had to extend `get_actions` plus define `has_delete_permission`. The `has_delete_permission` solution does not get rid of the action from the dropdown for me:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ....

    def get_actions(self, request):
        #Disable delete
        actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        #Disable delete
        return False
```

Not including it in `actions = ['your_custom_action']`, only works for the custom actions (defs) you have defined for that model. The solution `AdminSite.disable_action('delete_selected')`, disables it for all models, so you would have to explicitly include them later per each modelAdmin

Comment: I don't understand why returning has_delete_permission as false does not get rid of the action. I had to do both in django 1.6.6

Comment: You can just use `actions = None` instead of `get_actions()`.

Comment: That would disable all actions, not just the delete, no?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, my bad lol. I was using this answer to help disable all actions, but you should be able to specify the specific actions you want

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense

Comment: `has_delete_permission` seems enough for me to disable delete everywhere. `del actions['delete_selected']` raises key error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Simply disable the `yourapp.delete_yourmodel` permission for that user or the group to which (s)he belongs.

Comment: This doesn't work in Django 1.3 and earlier versions, because of this issue https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8060

It's fixed in Django 1.4.

Answer (score 9):

Well you probably are using:

```
AdminSite.disable_action('delete_selected')
```

For further control just implement your own admin and set its actions to whatever you need:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['whatever', 'actions']
```

Reference: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-a-site-wide-action

Comment: Doesn't work. Doesn't affect the individual page. Just disables the action when browsing the list.

Answer (score 5):

The solutions here are already nice, but I prefer to have it as a reusable mixin, like this:

```
class NoDeleteAdminMixin:
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

You can use this in all your admins where you want to prevent deletion like this:

```
class MyAdmin(NoDeleteAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')`

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.disable_action)

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but still, it may help someone.

Assuming that OP's

> ... user can still click on an item and then there's the red Delete link at the bottom.

refers to the red button in the "change" view. This button can be removed by extending the `ModelAdmin.change_view` method as follows:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url,
                               extra_context=dict(show_delete=False))
```

You can do the same with `show_save`, and `show_save_and_continue`. More info and alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202294).

Also note that, as of version 2.1, Django has a separate `has_view_permission` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission)), which **may be a better option**, depending on your use case.