# Cannot hide "Save and add another" button in Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to hide all the "Save" buttons in Django's Admin's Change Form, for a specific model, when certain conditions are met. Therefore, I override the `changeform_view` method in the relevant `ModelAdmin`, like so:

```
def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    obj = collection_management_MammalianLine.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    if obj:
        if not (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='Lab manager').exists() or request.user == obj.created_by):
            extra_context['show_save'] = False
            extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
            extra_context['show_save_and_add_another'] = False
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    return super(MammalianLinePage, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

With this code, I can successfully hide the "Save" and "Save and continue" buttons, but not the "Save and add another" one. I can see that `submit_line.html` contains the following three lines:

```
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
```

My question is: why can I hide the "Save" and "Save and continue" buttons, but not the "Save and add another" one? Even though the relevant templatetag (show_save_and_continue) is in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other keys are checked for in the passed context except `show_save_and_continue`. Django [always sets this directly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py#L59-L62).

```
'show_save_and_add_another': (
        context['has_add_permission'] and not is_popup and
        (not save_as or context['add'])
    ),
```

You can patch the `submit_row` template tag function to first check the `context` dictionary for `show_save_and_add_another`.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
    """
    Display the row of buttons for delete and save.
    """
    change = context['change']
    is_popup = context['is_popup']
    save_as = context['save_as']
    show_save = context.get('show_save', True)
    show_save_and_continue = context.get('show_save_and_continue', True)
    show_save_and_add_another = context.get('show_save_and_add_another', False)
    ctx = Context(context)
    ctx.update({
        'show_delete_link': (
            not is_popup and context['has_delete_permission'] and
            change and context.get('show_delete', True)
        ),
        'show_save_as_new': not is_popup and change and save_as,
        'show_save_and_add_another': (
            context.get('show_save_and_add_another', None) or
            (context['has_add_permission'] and not is_popup and
            (not save_as or context['add']))
        ),
        'show_save_and_continue': not is_popup and context['has_change_permission'] and show_save_and_continue,
        'show_save': show_save,
    })
    return ctx
```

**Edit**

*Steps to patch the "admin/submit_line.html" inclusion tag*

1. Create a `templatetags` folder at the same level of `models.py` and `views.py`
2. Create `__init__.py` in the `templatetags` folder
3. Copy [django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py) to `templatetags/admin_modify.py`.
4. Overwrite `submit_row` function definition with the one above.

**Note that** this is applicable for *Django 2.0* and below.

For recent Django versions, find a context mix that allows this expression to be `False`.*e.g.*

```
has_add_permission and not is_popup and
(not save_as or add) and can_save
```

[See values for the names used in the above expression](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.1/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py#L52-L62).

Comment: What do you mean by "patch"?

Comment: I suppose in this specific scenario, it means to override the default implementation

Comment: Yes of course but how? I mean where should one put this code?

Comment: My answer is edited to show how to patch "admin/submit_line.html" inclusion tag. You should find the other answer straight to the point to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 19):

You may override **render_change_form** method in **ModelAdmin** subclass.
In this method **obj** is available as argument and you can check certain conditions.

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        context.update({
            'show_save': False,
            'show_save_and_continue': False,
            'show_save_and_add_another': False,
            'show_delete': False
        })
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)
```

Comment: Does not remove save and add another

Comment: context.update({
            'show_save_and_add_another': False
        }) 
works as for django 3.1

Answer (score 5):

### EDIT:

As of Django 3.1, the approach from the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49560378) should simply work:

```
...
extra_context['show_save_and_add_another'] = False
...
```

See [this Django commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b9db423d3c525697ad59b14c0dcaaccf2770d062) for details.

### OLD ANSWER:

### summary

Some additional options:

1. Set `save_as=True` on your `ModelAdmin`. As described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_as), this will replace the "*Save and add another*" button with a "*Save as new*" button. This may not be ideal for all cases, but it is the simplest solution as far as I know.
2. Apply a monkey patch for the `has_add_permission` method on your `ModelAdmin`, so it returns `False` during the call to `super().change_view` (or `changeform_view`).
3. Override the `TemplateResponse.content` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/template-response/#the-rendering-process)) to simply hide (or remove) the `submit-row` element, which contains the buttons, from the HTML.

### details option 1

The simplest option is to set `save_as=True` on the `ModelAdmin`. This will replace the "*Save and add another*" button with a "*Save as new*" button. As a result, assuming the other save buttons have been disabled, any changes made to the current object can only be saved as a new object. The current object will remain unchanged.

Basic implementation:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True

    # your other code here, such as the extended changeform_view
```

### details option 2

The [submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html) template shows which context variables are used to show/hide the save and delete buttons. Most of those context variables can be set via the `extra_context` in `changeform_view` (or `change_view`). However, as the OP showed, we cannot simply override `show_save_and_add_another` in that manner.

As pointed out in [@Oluwafemi-Sule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561655)'s answer,
`show_save_and_add_another` is set in [admin_modify.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py#L59-L62), which creates the context for [submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html).

Upon closer inspection of the source, it is tempting to override the `has_add_permission` context variable, because that determines the value of `show_save_and_add_another`. However, simply adding `has_add_permission=False` to `extra_context` does not work in `Django < 2.1`, because the change will be undone by the [ModelAdmin.render_change_form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1061) method.

Fortunately, rather than overriding the template or patching the template tags, we can simply trick Django into thinking that `has_add_permission` is `False`, using a [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626250) in `change_view`:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    # use extra_context to disable the other save (and/or delete) buttons
    extra_context = dict(show_save=False, show_save_and_continue=False, show_delete=False)
    # get a reference to the original has_add_permission method
    has_add_permission = self.has_add_permission
    # monkey patch: temporarily override has_add_permission so it returns False
    self.has_add_permission = lambda __: False
    # get the TemplateResponse from super (python 3)
    template_response = super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    # restore the original has_add_permission (otherwise we cannot add anymore)
    self.has_add_permission = has_add_permission
    # return the result
    return template_response
```

This also works if you replace `change_view` by `changeform_view`, as used by the OP ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.change_view)).

Note: obviously, this option can only be used if `has_add_permission=False` does not interfere with other things in your change view.

### details option 3

Based on this [example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/template-response/#the-rendering-process), it is also possible simply to hide (or even remove) the `submit-row` from the rendered HTML for the `change_view`:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='',
                extra_context=None):
    # get the default template response
    template_response = super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url,
                                            extra_context)
    # here we simply hide the div that contains the save and delete buttons
    template_response.content = template_response.rendered_content.replace(
        '<div class="submit-row">',
        '<div class="submit-row" style="display: none">')
    return template_response
```

As noted, we can also remove the `submit-row` section altogether, but that is a bit more work.

This is simpler than option 2, but more fragile.

Answer (score 3):

If no one is against, then I publish my little **monkey patch**.
This can be inserted anywhere and called up from the `settings` file (preferably at the very end).

```
# Hide "save_and_add_another" button
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_modify

submit_row = admin_modify.submit_row
def submit_row_custom(context):
    ctx = submit_row(context)
    ctx['show_save_and_add_another'] = False
    return ctx
admin_modify.submit_row = submit_row_custom
```

Comment: thanks @Vyaches. It really work on my project. 
My django version is 3.1.0

Comment: isn't this called monkey patching and quite dangerous? (I already did this in other contexts, and it always felt really uncomfortable ;-)

Comment: @benzkji You are absolutely right, but I chose this option to achieve the result.
Made a correction to my answer for better understanding. Thx u!

Comment: perfect, thx for the update. so, it didn't bite you yet? ;-)=

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative way to hide the "Save and add another" button.

**In form.py**

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Media:
          js = ('admin/yourjsfile.js',)
```

**In yourjsfile.js**

```
(function($) {
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the "Save and add another" button
    $("input[name='_addanother']").attr('type','hidden');
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

I had same issue  for hiding that button. 
I've tested it in Django 1.11 and it did work, but I think there are better ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I propose (changed option 3 of djvg's answer) removing this html input element with regex as with this example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        template_response = super(MyModelAdmin, self).add_view(
            request, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
        # POST request won't have html response
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # removing Save and add another button: with regex
            template_response.content = re.sub("<input.*?_addanother.*?(/>|>)", "", template_response.rendered_content)
        return template_response
```

`_addanother` is this html element's id

Answer (score 0):

To remove **"Save and add another" button**, return **"False"** in **"has_add_permission()"** as shown below and I don't know why we cannot remove **"Save and add another" button** by setting **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_save_and_another']"** in **"changeform_view()"**:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```