# How to remove DELETE button from django admin page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, button, django-admin

I want to remove the Delete button from django admin page
as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Show the admin code for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Django Admin how do I disable the Delete link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043843/in-django-admin-how-do-i-disable-the-delete-link)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) definition you can override the function [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission). If you wish to remove the delete button for all users you can just return `False`

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
```

I would suggest however that you allow superusers to still be able to delete

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return request.user.is_superuser
```

Comment: To clarify; this does **not** *hide* or *remove* the delete button. This makes the user not able to delete the object. This can be a problem for objects that are suppose to be implicitly deleted due to deleting a related object when having `on_delete=CASCADE`.

Comment: Nice answer. One small correction: `request.user.is_superuser()` is not callable as this is a boolean field, not a method. Edited the code. should be `request.user.is_superuser`

Answer (score 4):

You can override the function [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) to prevent deletion

```py
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
```

Overriding [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) will prevent deletion in other model pages which have relation (with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`) to your model. **To allow deletion** in other pages but **prevent the deletion** in the model's admin page, You can conditionally return `False` like:

```py
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if f"{model._meta.app_label}/{model._meta.model_name}" in request.path:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove **"Delete" button**, set **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_delete']"** in **"changeform_view()"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_delete'] = False # Here
        # extra_context['show_save'] = False
        # extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

You can also remove **"Delete" button** by setting **"False"** to **"show_delete"** in **"context.update()"** in **"render_change_form()"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        context.update({
            'show_delete': False, # Here
            # 'show_save': False,
            # 'show_save_and_continue': False,
        })
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)
```